# Why $1 output is nothing?

Tags: bash

I wrote a simple bash script and in the end of that I tried to test positional arguments like $0, $1, ...

```
echo please enter your name
read name
if [ -z "$name" ]
then
        echo please enter your name
fi
if [ -n "$name" ]
then
        echo Thank you so much
fi
echo $0
echo $1
echo $2
echo $3
```

After I run that, the output was:

```
please enter your name
j
Thank you so much
/bin/reza.sh
```

Why just $0 had output and other had nothing?

Comment: definitely you didn't pass `$1` when running the script...

Comment: $1 is your first command line argument, which you have never passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments you enter to a script are take in the order $1,$2,$3 and so on.

In this `testscript`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $0 #Gives you the command/script name itself
echo $1 #Gives you the first argument
echo $2 #Gives you the second argument
echo $3 #Gives you the third argument
echo $@ #Gives you all arguments
echo $# #Gives you the total number of arguments excluding the script name
```

So the result of

```
$./testscript a b c
```

is

```
./testscript
a
b
c
a b c
3
```

If the argument is not assigned, its value is null or nothing will be printed.

```
$ printf "%sThere is nothing before this.\n" $1
```

gives you :

```
There is nothing before this.
```

**Note:** Don't use `echo` to test arguments, echo will append a newline at the end automatically as in bash.

Comment: That was a great answer. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Run it like below

```
./bin/reza.sh first second third
please enter your name
monk
Thank you so much
/bin/reza.sh
first
second
third
```

Also, $0 is file name of the script itself.

Comment: I was very confuse that how positional arguments works. Thanks for your helps.